# Convert char to int and find the difference using java

Tags: java

Suppose i have a number as 68, then this number should give me answer as 2. basically I am trying to find the difference of this number i.e.. 6-8 = -2 (actually i want to ignore if it is +2 or -2). My code should follow these steps 
1.Convert number into String
2.Extract each char using charAt method
3.Convert char to int and find the difference
Here is my code

```
    int number = 68, convertInt, difference;
    String str = String.valueOf(number);
    char ch = 0;

    for(int a=0; a<str.length(); a++){
        ch = str.charAt(a);
        convertInt = Character.getNumericValue(ch);
        // here I'm unable to do the difference
    }
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()`

Comment: Since you assume the number to have exactly two digits, you don't need the loop. Just `char a = str.charAt(0); char b = str.charAt(1);`

Comment: Also, with the magic of `number / 10` and `number % 10` there is no need to go via Strings.

Comment: Actually, my input is 45862 and 4-5=1, 5-8=3, 8-6=2, 6-2=4 and last number should be same as 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
    ch = str.charAt(i);  
    int di = Character.getNumericValue(ch);
    char ch2 = str.charAt(i + 1);
    int di2 = Character.getNumericValue(ch2);
    int diff = Math.abs(di - di2);
    System.out.println(diff);
}
```

This might work.

Comment: And why do you think so? Don't post a bunch of code lines without any explanation.